# Group actions producing an automorphism of a group formed from a power-set to itself and symmetric difference

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

Let the group $G$ act on the set $X$.

For $g \in G$ and $A \in P(X)$ set $g.A = \{g.a \mid a \in A\} = \{x \in X \mid \exists a \in A: x = g.a \}$. this defines an action of $G$ on $P(x)$. I 'm trying to show that this action is an automorphism given the map $\phi: A \mapsto g.A$, where $\phi: (P(x),\Delta) \rightarrow (P(x),\Delta)$.

Here, $A \Delta B = (A - B) \cup (B - A)$ the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.

From the definitions, I know I have to show that for $A,B \in P(X)$, we have to show that $\phi (A \Delta B) = \phi(A) \ \Delta \ \phi(B)$. However, I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you having problems showing that $\phi(A\Delta B) = \phi(A) \Delta \phi(B)$? That proves that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of the group $(P(X),\Delta)$. The only other thing you have to show is that $\phi$ is a bijection. But if you already know that $A \mapsto g .A$ defines an action of $G$ on $A$, then that implies immediately that $\phi$ is a bijection.

Comment: I am having problems showing that $\phi (A \Delta B) = \phi(A) \Delta \phi(B)$.

Comment: It's routine. Let $x \in A \Delta B$ then $\phi(x) \in A \cup B$. But, since $\phi$ is a bijection and $x \not\in A \cap B$, $\phi(x) \not\in A \cap B$. So $\phi(A \Delta B) \subseteq \phi(A) \Delta \phi(B)$. For the other containment just do the same with $\phi^{-1}$.